# Can we show that two matrices are unitarily equivalent?

Tags: matrix

Is it possible to show that matrix `a1` defined as

```
 a1 = {{-((
     Sqrt[1 - x] Sqrt[2 - x - Sqrt[4 + x (-4 + x (1 - 2 y)^2)]] Sqrt[
      Sqrt[4 + x (-4 + x (1 - 2 y)^2)]/(
      x + Sqrt[4 + x (-4 + x (1 - 2 y)^2)] - 2 x y)])/Sqrt[
     4 + x (-4 + x (1 - 2 y)^2)]), 0}, {0, Sqrt[
    2 - x - Sqrt[4 + x (-4 + x (1 - 2 y)^2)]]/(
    2 Sqrt[Sqrt[4 + x (-4 + x (1 - 2 y)^2)]/(
     x + Sqrt[4 + x (-4 + x (1 - 2 y)^2)] - 2 x y)])}};
```

is unitarily equivalent either to `a2` or `a3` defined as

```
a2 = {{Sqrt[1 - x] Sqrt[y], 0}, {0, Sqrt[y]}};
a3 = {{Sqrt[1 - y], 0}, {0, Sqrt[1 - y] Sqrt[1 - x]}};
```

Answer (score 3):

All three of your matrices are diagonal, and two diagonal matrices are unitarily equivalent if and only if they have the same entries on the diagonals.  This is because unitarily transforming a matrix does not change the values or multiplicities of its eigenvalues, and the eigenvalues of a diagonal matrix are simply the entries on its diagonal.

So in principle all you need to do is to see if `a1` and `a2` are equivalent is to see if there are any solutions to either of the following systems of equations:

```
Solve[{a1[[1, 1]] == a2[[1, 1]], a1[[2, 2]] == a2[[2, 2]]}, {x, y}]
Solve[{a1[[1, 1]] == a2[[2, 2]], a1[[2, 2]] == a2[[1, 1]]}, {x, y}]
```

Similar code could be run to compare `a1` & `a3`.  In each case you have a system of two equations in two unknowns, so you may find that the solution space is zero-dimensional, one-dimensional, or two-dimensional depending on the structure of the equations.  Given the complexity of your expressions in `a1` and the relative simplicity of `a2` and `a3`, I highly doubt that they are similar for `x` and `y`. But anything's possible, I suppose.

Unfortunately, Mathematica does not return a result for the commands above, probably due (again) to the horrendous complexity of the expressions.  I ran the code for about 3–4 hours on my computer with no results.  There may be other techniques that can be used to address this problem, but I will leave it to others to figure them out.

Comment: It is quite easy to find values of `x` and `y` for which none are equivalent.  You might be able to find values for which they are.